# JavaScript private methods, asynchronous access

Tags: javascript

I'm using a pattern like the one shown below to create a javascript library that has private and public methods.  The idea is that the page that includes this library would call MYLIB.login() and provide two functions for when the user clicks OK, or Cancel.

```
var MYLIB = function() {
    //  private data and functions
    var showForm = function() {
        //  create and show the form
    };
    var onOK = function() {
        //  hide the form, do some internal stuff, then…
        okFunction();
    };
    var onCancel = function() {
        //  hide the form, do some internal stuff, then...
        cancelFunction();
    };

    var okFunction = null;
var cancelFunction = null;

    //  public functions 
    return {
        login : function(okf, cancelf) {
           okFunction = okf;
           calcelFunction = cancelf;
           showForm();
        },
    };  
}();
```

My question is about getting the buttons in the form to call the internal functions onOK and onCancel, which are private.  The buttons look like this:

```
<button onclick="onOK();">OK</button>
<button onclick="onCancel();">Cancel</button>
```

I can get it to work if I make the functions public, but then I may as well make everything public.  How can I do what I want?  Coming from a C++/Java background, trying to be a good OO guy.  Thanks.

Comment: You will have to change your implementation to meet your needs. Currently you only expose `login`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to go about it, but from what I see the onOK and onCancel have to be public because you need to access them from outside the class. You could vreate a public function to handel these actions like:

```
this.setStatus = function(status){
  // check if the conection is on before calling the functions and stuff like that
  if(status) onCancel();
  else onOK();
}
```

it actually depends on where you want to go with this in the log run. Javascript provides a lot of OOP stuff, but is very different than C++/Java.

Tip: if you want to use private functions I would encourage you to use priviledgiat functions to work with the private methods (http://cuzztuts.blogspot.ro/search/label/oop) , also keep in mind that it's important the order in witch you declare your vars.